# Get total time duration by group from list

Tags: c#, linq

[image]

I have this list "userLoginTrials" and have to do the following:

- Get every Item with the same UserId and
- check if "_logoutTimeStamp" is not null
- then calculate the difference between "_trialTimeStamp" and "_logoutTimeStamp" which results in the duration.

Simple: I have to get the total login-duration of every User in the list.

Comment: can you show us the code that you wrote till now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the job (note that I used the none underscored versions of your variables as I assume they are private to your class):

```
var data = from u in userLoginTrials
           where u.LogoutTimeStamp != null
           group u by u.UserId into g
           select new
           {
               UserId = g.Key,
               TotalTime = g.Sum(t => t.LogoutTimeStamp - t.TrialTimeStamp)
           };
```

Comment: Typically I would actually use `(t.LogoutTimeStamp ?? DateTime.Now) - t.TrialTimeStamp)` assuming that null means they are still logged in. :)

Comment: OP said in the question to check it's not null, so doing that in this case would be incorrect.

Comment: I know...was more of a message to the OP, in case that could be helpful... :) I did actually upvote your answer (and correct your `=` for `-`).

Comment: Thanks for the edit, took me a little while to figure out what you had done as the viewer doesn't make it obvious when `=` changes to `-` :)

Comment: Also, I'd stay away from using `DateTime.Now` as it makes testing difficult. And it's [evil](https://twitter.com/rasmusnu/status/424049571107700736)!

Comment: A LogoutTimeStamp is only created if the user is really clicking on the logout-button. E.g.: Closing a tab is not a logout. Thanks David and Aron for the snippet and editions. I wonder how I can get TotalTime because both TrialTimeStamp and LogoutTimeStamp are DateTime objects.

Comment: @rectoplasmus `TotalTime` in my example is a `TimeSpan` object which should give you exactly what you need.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like the following one:

```
var output = userLoginTrials.GroupBy(x=>x.UserId)
                            .Select(x=>new {
                                UserId = x.Key,
                                TotalDuration = x.Where(y=>y.LogoutTimeStamp!=null)
                                                 .Sum(y=>(y.LogoutTimeStamp-y.TrialTimeStamp))
                            });
```

Initially, we make a group by of the objects inside the `userLoginTrials` list. Then, for each created group we create a projection to an anonymous type with properties, one would be the `Key` of the group, the `UserId` and the other the `TotalDuration` of the User. In order we achieve the latter, we filter the elements of the group, in order to get the elements with `LogoutTimeStamp` **not** equal to null. Then we sum for all of these elements the difference between the `LogoutTimeStamp` and `TrialTimeStamp`.

**update**

As DavidG correctly pointed out in the comments a better approach would be the following one:

```
var output = userLoginTrials.Where(x=>x.LogoutTimeStamp!=null)
                            .GroupBy(x=>x.UserId)
                            .Select(x=>new {
                                UserId = x.Key,
                                TotalDuration = x.Sum(y=>(y.LogoutTimeStamp-y.TrialTimeStamp))
                            });
```

This way you take only the items of `userLoginTrials` list that have a `LogoutTimeStamp` different from `null` and then you make the group by to these items.

Comment: Personally I'd do the `Where` before the `Select` as it looks tidier :)

Comment: @DavidG you are correct dude. I didn't notice that. I will write an update. Thank you !

Comment: Of course it does mean no entry for users that have not yet logged out, but I assume that's fine for the OP.

Answer (score 0):

```
var groups = userLoginTrials.GroupBy(u => u.UserId);
foreach(var group in groups)
{
    // group.Key is the UserId
    // group will contain an IEnumerable<UserLoginTrial> with that UserId
    foreach(var userLoginTrial in group)
    {
    // Add your logic here
    }
}
```